# Pass the tables in DF one by one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 300 tables in the source side from which I am trying to connect and publish the data  by creating a pipeline . However I am facing a index out of range exception for some of the tables though the table names are valid from the source side

My Code is given below

```
#Create a pandas DF from a Json file and extract certain columns like tabname,colname,col length and data type
df = metadata_extract(file_name)

#Create a instance of an object to run a pipeline and after passing the connection details 
pipeline = Pipeline(server,source_type,source_name,database_name,user_name,password)
    tables = pd.unique(df["tab_name"])

#create a function to extract and process the tables from the source system
   def get_table_data():  
     for i in range(len(tables)):
          current_tab = df[df["tab_name"] == tables[i]].reset_index()
          print (current_tab)
          data = pipeline.process_table(current_tab) 
          print (data)
    
          
     
get_table_data()
```

I am trying to pass all the unique tables from a DF to get source table data

however I am getting Index out of range for some of the table names

I am getting a error like this for the below line

the current_tab print stmt gives output around 300 tables like below

```
282  15940  Schema1.TABLE1                Colname           CHAR

283  15941  Schema1.TABLE1                Colname           CHAR

284  15942  Schema1.TABLE1                Colname           CHAR

285  15943  Schema1.TABLE1                Colname           CHAR

286  15944  Schema1.TABLE1                Colname           CHAR

[287 rows x 5 columns]
    index        TableName ColumnName ColumnDataType ColumnLength        
 0  15945  Schema1.table2      Colname           CHAR            2        
 1  15946  Schema1.table2      Colname           CUKY            5
[154 rows x 5 columns]

 index      TableName        ColumnName ColumnDataType ColumnLength 
 0    15504  Schema1.TABLE3             Colname1           CHAR            3 
 1    15505  Schema1.TABLE3             Colname2           CHAR            3 
 2    15506  Schema1.TABLE3             Colname3           CHAR            3 
 3    15507  Schema1.TABLE3             Colname4           CHAR            3
4    15508  Schema1.TABLE3             Colname5           CHAR            3
```

I am getting this error below

```
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.metadata_trigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure   
Exception: IndexError: list index out of range
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 407, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 649, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
  File "C:\Users\metadata_trigger\__init__.py", line 31, in main
    get_tables()
  File "C:\Users\metadata_trigger\__init__.py", line 26, in get_tables    
    data = pipeline.process_tab(current_tab)
  File "C:\Users\.venv\lib\site-packages\mdt\pipeline.py", line 78, in process_tab
    select = self.generate_select_query(df)
  File "C:\Users\.venv\lib\site-packages\mdt\pipeline.py", line 68, in generate_select_query
    table_name = str(df["table_nm"][0]).split(".")[1]
```

however I am sure there is a value for tablename at the index position 1 as seen above

***I would need to get all the source table data printed in the console but currently only one table is printed in the console. For the others I am seeing as index out of range exception***

Comment: Please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: I have added the error with traceback